# Magento 2.1.9 upgrade to 2.2.0 - Error on setup:upgrade with Magento_Sales table get error when upgrade

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade-script

Upgrading magento from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 and during the automatic `bin/magento setup:upgrade` process, it runs all upgrades fine until it reaches the magento_sales table where it produces this error.

```
Upgrading data.. Error converting field product_options in table sales_order_item where item_id= 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13, 17, 21, 26, 43, 46, 48, 69, 70, 71, 76, 81, 82, 91, 98, 101, 105, 108, 111, 116, 117, 122, 123, 127, 131, 135, 139, 141, 144, 145, 154, 164, 166, 171, 172, 173, 7659, 7660, 7671, 7672, 7681 using Magento\Sales\Setup\SerializedDataConverter. Fix data or replace with a valid value.
```

How can I solve this error. Please help.